# Regular expression clean results

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to extract the words from this string with PHP :

```
$string= '\'banana\', "orange", "apple"';
```

Using this pattern :

```
/([\'"])(.*?)\1/
```

But it gives me this results :

```
array(3) {
    [0] array(3) {
        [0] "'banana'"
        [1] ""orange""
        [2] ""apple""
    }
    [1] array(3) {
        [0] "'"
        [1] ""
        [2] ""
    }
    [2] array(3) {
        [0] "banana"
        [1] "orange"
        [2] "apple"
    }
}
```

Is these a way I can clean it up to just :

```
array(3) {
    [0] "banana"
    [1] "orange"
    [2] "apple"
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With regex, you can just extract word characters using the `\w` matcher.
Put it together with a Global flag, and I believe you'll get what you want :)

See [this example](https://regex101.com/r/sN0sT4/2)

Comment: That's amazing! It worked. It returned this :
array(1) {
    [0] array(3) {
        [0] "banana"
        [1] "orange"
        [2] "apple"
    }
}
Is it possible to only return one level?

Comment: Regex is amazing on many levels if it's used for the right thing :) I recommend that you take 1 or 2 hours off during your free time to learn it. There are many resources out there, just have to pick your favourite one.

Comment: Btw, what do you mean by 'return one level'? Do you mean you want `\'banana\', "orange", "apple"` to return `banana orange apple`? If so, then what you can do is just do a 'join' on the array.

Comment: Thank you so much @SWLim, currently the results are displayed as an array inside another array ( nested arrays ), I only want one array with those words. Is it possible?

Comment: As I am not sure what the best practice is, I'd say you could add `[0]` behind the returned result to get that second level. Example `preg_grep("/\w+/", array($string))[0]`. Then again, I'm not sure if this is the best and/or the safest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split` and describe all you want to remove and where you want to cut the string, then add the flag `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` to filter empty parts.

```
$subject = '\'banana\', "orange", "apple"';
$pattern = '~["\'](?:,\s*["\']|\z)|\A["\']~';

$result = preg_split($pattern, $subject, -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);

print_r($result);
```

Obviously this way doesn't check if each item is well enclosed between the same type of quotes, but is it really necessary?